# Joining rows from 2 tables when value is both available and not available

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables 'JobCount' & 'JobSchedule' with respective rows as shown below :

```
JOBID COUNT
1     3
2     2

JOBID EMPID
1     Rahul
1     Mohit
2     Madhu
```

The goal is to find out which JobId requirement is fulfilled and which are not. A JobId requirement is said to be fulfilled when we have the same number of rows in JobSchedule as defined by Count column in JobCount table for a particular JobId.
So my output should be something like :

```
OUTPUT

JOBID EMPID REQUIREMENT
1     Rahul T
1     Mohit T
1     NULL  F
2     Madhu T
2     NULL  F
```

I am looking for a single query which can be used as dataset query in my jrxml.
So procedures or insert statements for temp table are not helpful. Is there any other way ? Please help.

Let me know if need any more information required.

Comment: So. this would be easier to display on the top table... no? Just show the JOBID, Count, and T/F if it is satisfied. Would this suffice? It would prevent the listing of every employee and a bunch of NULL for those that are missing, making it more clear

Comment: No I would require employee names to display in the report.

Comment: Fair enough, i provided an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand the available jobs to do this, and assign numbers to them. Once you do that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will easily do what you want, as in:

With the data:

```
create table jobcount (
  jobid int,
  count int
);

insert into jobcount (jobid, count) values (1, 3);
insert into jobcount (jobid, count) values (2, 2);

create table jobschedule (
  jobid int,
  empid varchar(20)
);

insert into jobschedule (jobid, empid) values (1, 'Rahul');
insert into jobschedule (jobid, empid) values (1, 'Mohit');
insert into jobschedule (jobid, empid) values (2, 'Madhu');
```

The query would be:

```
with
d as ( -- produces 10 digits
  select 0 as x union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
  union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
),
n as ( -- generates numbers from 0 to 999
  select d1.x + d2.x * 10 + d3.x * 100 as x
  from d as d1
  cross join d as d2
  cross join d as d3
),
available as ( -- expand available jobs and assign numbers to them
  select
    c.jobid, n.x as rn
  from jobcount c
  join n on n.x > 0 and n.x <= c.count
),
filled as ( -- assigns numbers to filled jobs
  select
    jobid,
    empid,
    row_number() over(partition by jobid order by empid) as rn
  from jobschedule
)
select -- main query that matches available against filled jobs
  a.jobid, 
  b.empid,
  case when b.empid is not null then 'T' else 'F' end as requirement
from available a
left join filled b on a.jobid = b.jobid and a.rn = b.rn
order by a.jobid, requirement desc
```

Result:

```
jobid        empid                 requirement  
-----------  --------------------  -----------
1            Mohit                 T            
1            Rahul                 T            
1            <null>                F            
2            Madhu                 T            
2            <null>                F
```

You'll need to add an extra row in the `n` CTE if you have job positions with more than 999 openings each.

Comment: Thanks @The Impaler. I would try it.

Comment: The insertion statements are only included for the example. The main **single** query is the one you want and assumes the data is already in the tables. Just use that one.

Comment: Yes I missed it. Understood your solution. Will try now.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it would be easier to show if the job requirement is fulfilled on the `JobCount` table. This would eliminate the propagated `NULL` rows. Or, just show the requirement, and the currently filled employees. Here is how you would do a few versions of this

```
--sample data
declare @JobCount table (JOBID int, [COUNT] int)
insert into @JobCount
values
(1,3),
(2,2)


declare @JobSchedule table (JOBID int, EMPID varchar(16))
insert into @JobSchedule
values
(1,'Rahul'),
(1,'Mohit'),
(2,'Madhu'),
(2,'Rahmad')


--clean version, just showing the job
select distinct
    c.JobID
    ,c.COUNT
    ,REQUIREMENT = case when count(s.EMPID) over (partition by s.JOBID order by (select null)) = c.COUNT then 'T' else 'F' end
from @JobCount c
inner join @JobSchedule s on s.JOBID = c.JOBID


--clean version, adding in how many emps are needed
select distinct
    c.JobID
    ,c.COUNT
    ,NEEDED = c.COUNT - count(s.EMPID) over (partition by s.JOBID order by (select null))
    ,REQUIREMENT = case when count(s.EMPID) over (partition by s.JOBID order by (select null)) = c.COUNT then 'T' else 'F' end
from @JobCount c
inner join @JobSchedule s on s.JOBID = c.JOBID

--version showing the current emps in the job
select 
    c.JobID
    ,c.COUNT
    ,s.EMPID
    ,REQUIREMENT = case when count(s.EMPID) over (partition by s.JOBID order by (select null)) = c.COUNT then 'T' else 'F' end
from @JobCount c
inner join @JobSchedule s on s.JOBID = c.JOBID
```

Comment: Thanks @scsimon , your answer is close enough but I needed the null rows too. And only the null rows should show 'F' under requirement column.

Comment: Ok. I can’t imagine the point of NULL in this scenario but good luck.